# Access child component's prop inside parent <template> in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

In a radio button component in Vue.js, its value is bound to the component using `:value`, and the corresponding text description (label) is obtained via a mapping like `ValToLabel[val]`:

```js
<template>
   <my-radio :value="val" :label="ValtoLabel[val]"></my-radio>
</template>
```

Writing `val` twice is annoying and might cause inconsistency in the future development. I'd like to implement something like:

```js
<template>
   <my-radio :value="val" :label="ValtoLabel[self.value]"></my-radio>
</template>
```

where `self` is this `my-radio` component, and `self.value` is equal to `val` which is bound into the component.

Or, more, can we do something like this inside a mustache:

```js
<template>
   <my-radio :value="val">{{ ValtoLabel[self.value] }}</my-radio>
</template>
```

I wonder is this possible in Vue.js, of course, without modification to the code of the `my-radio` component.

Comment: So, what happens, when you try those things?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap my-radio in your component. Here you will have the power to set your interface with the component.

```
<template>
   <super-my-radio :my-value="val" />
</template>
```

So you do not modify the component itself. And the readability of the code in this case seems to me much better.

Comment: Ok. Using HOC is a practical idea. I agree.